# Specifying the groovy distribution in intelliJ when creating a new project

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, groovy

I've been following [these directions](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-module-with-groovy-support.html) to set up a project in IntelliJ with groovy support, but I get blocked at step 3 because the location of my groovy distribution is not specified, and IJ refuses to accept the copy of groovy that I pulled from macports into the /opt/local/bin folder. (The OK button in the navigation window is grayed out when I try to point at /opt/local/bin, and there's no message indicating what it would consider acceptable.) Does anyone know what location I should be pointing at, if not that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the groovy home directory itself, not the directory where the symlink to the executable script is located. With **MacPorts** it would be:

`/opt/local/share/java/groovy`

Answer (score 5):

For me, running on Mac with HomeBrew, it was

```
/usr/local/Cellar/groovy/2.4.5/libexec
```